# Incompatibility between job and field of study

Tags: mathematics, postdocs, job, industry, ranking

Finding jobs for Ph.D graduate in mathematics is the main concern. Available options are namely in general industry and academia. I see, for instance, some Ph.D in math (algebraic geometry)  working in Bank sector! This incompatibility
between field of study and job might back to the rank of math department of graduated person. 
There maybe exists some other reasons. But I want to know about the upper bound of ranks of departments might be considered as top ranks? Additionally, which university ranking is most reliable in industry sector and in academia?

Comment: There's also government jobs. Mathematics is not a profession (like engineering or dentistry) but a field of learning. There are niches within mathematics like actuary and perhaps statistician though. I don't really follow your question beyond that though.

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding your question the way you've written it.  Are you concerned that if you took an unrelated job in industry, that that might lower the ranking of the program you graduated from?  Are you asking if the ranking of the program you graduated from will affect your employability?

Comment: @aparente001 It is my confusion if someone takes an unrelated job in industry? How does a pure mathematics postgraduated can start a job in Banking sector?

Comment: @user40491 - I think you just submit an application.  You might want to brush up on your English grammar basics and have someone check your cover letter and CV.

Comment: @aparente001 !!!!

Comment: @user40491 - Again, I'm not sure what you're trying to convey.

Answer (score 3):

As a graduate PhD your options are staying in academia and moving to industry, as you correctly point out. If you stay in academia, be it as research staff or as postdoc, it is generally because there is a interest in your field of study. In industry however, especially with rather specialized studies, you are not hired for your research to this point. With a PhD you have proven you are capable of independently solving challenging problems. And math/physics PhDs are generally considered as being good at working with numbers and abstract concepts. This is why they end up in the banking sector or working for insurance companies. It doesn't matter if your PhD is from a high ranking university or not, once you move past a certain point of specialization there is simply no demand for the research you are working on, you are hired for the skills you developed during your PhD